# Что это за условие?

Tags: python

Что значит в одной строчке? Т.е. нужно вводить все данные в одной строчке, или можно вводить всё по отдельности, как в моём коде?

На вход в программе подаются сведения о сдаче экзаменов учениками 9─х классов, некоторой средней школы. В первой строке сообщается количество учеников N, которое не меньше 10, не превосходит 100. 
Каждая из N строк имеет следующий формат: <Фамилия><Имя><оценки> где<Фамилия>─строка, состоящая не более чем из 20 символов <Имя>─строка, состоящая не более чем из 15 символов <оценки>─через пробел три целых числа, соответствующие оценкам по пятибалльной системе. <Фамилия>, <Имя> и <оценки> разделены одним пробелом. Требуется написать программу, которая будет выводить на экран имена 3─х лучших по среднему баллу учеников.

```
 N=int(input())
 name1=0
 name2=0
 name3=0
 max1=0
 max2=0
 max3=0
 for i in range(N):
      a=input()
      b=input()
      o=int(input())
      p=int(input())
      z=int(input())
      g=o+p+z/3
      if g>=max1:
           max2=max1
           name3=name2
           name2=name1
           max1=g
           name1=b
      elif g>=max2:
           max3=max2
           name3=name2
           max2=g
           name2=b
      elif g>=max3:
           max3=g
           name3=b
print(name1,name2,name3)
```

Comment: Имена переменным лучше давать понятные, а то потом придется через пару недель исправлять/улучшать и начнутся вопросы к самому себе - что такое b, что такое g...

Answer (score 0):

Первое действие правильное: надо получить число N - количество строк, а далее нужно, считывая N строк, для каждой произвести разбиение по пробелу для получения данных, например, с помощью `str.split`.